# Java IO. Нужна помощь в настройке BufferedInputStream для чтения большого файла

Tags: java, io

Есть метод для чтения большого текстового файла, однако код кажется мне не корректным, и я хотел бы сделать его как-то избавиться от этого `if(amountData != -1)...`. Появился этот `if` в результате следующей проблемы: когда чтение файла подходило к концу, и оставалась последняя итерация цикла, размер буфера значительно превышал количество байт которое осталось для чтения, и в результате я имел в конце переменной в которую поместил данные которые прочитал из файла большое количество квадратов(не расшифрованных символов). Я так понял что эти квадраты это те `null` которые оказались в буфере не заполненными(остатка данных в файле не хватило), и что-бы избавиться от них я стал проверять сколько данных у меня реально прочитано. И это работает.

Я хотел бы отказаться от этой подпорки, и воспользоваться средствами стандартного API, но не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста.

```
private void read() {
    String path = "/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/target_text.txt";
    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(path))) {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int amountData = in.read(bytes, 0, 1024);


        while (amountData != -1 && amountData == 1024) {
            sb.append(new String(bytes, "UTF8"));
            amountData = in.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
        }

        if (amountData != -1) {
            byte[] residue = new byte[amountData];
            System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, residue, 0, residue.length);
            sb.append(new String(residue, "UTF8"));
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом, коллега, у вас 2 проблемы:

1. У вас уже есть буферизированный поток и на его фоне зачем еще раз городить огород с буфером `bytes`?
2. Более глобальная проблема состоит в том, что у вас есть текстовый файл с кодировкой UTF-8, который вы читаете как байтовый поток. При этом в кодировке UTF-8 длина символа местами 2 байта, местами и 1 байт, не считая выравнивающих битов и проч. ерунды. То есть читая его как байтовый поток с размером буфера 1024 байта вы гарантированно кое-где режете границы символов из-за чего и получаете квадратики.

Надо читать как поток символов UTF-8, тогда не будет проблем:

```
    final static int BUFFER_SIZE=1024;
    char[] buffer=new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
    int size;

    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), "UTF-8");
    do {
        size=in.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
        if(size > 0)
           sb.append(buffer, 0, size);
    } while(size==BUFFER_SIZE);
```

и это как раз тот случай когда надо использовать постфиксный цикл

Comment: так вы теряете хвост файла, если количество символов не кратно 1024 (а если поток тянет данные из сети, то заполнение буфера и совсем не гарантировано). Есть же типовое `while ( (size = in.read(buffer)) != -1 ) { sb.append( buffer, 0, size ); }`, зачем изобретать что-то еще?

Comment: @zRrr вы уверены, что хвост файла теряется? - садитесь "двойка"  :)))

Comment: Да, пойду посижу. На самом деле наоборот, для файла с кратным 1024 числом символов (в т.ч. файла нулевой длины) `sb.append` даст исключение, т.к. `size` будет равен `-1`. Замечание при потерю хвоста в случае неполного заполнения буфера остается в силе.

Comment: @zRrr По `sb.append()` - вы правы, я же не компилятор в конце-то концов и не тестировщик. Я написал на коленках общую идею реализации. А по-поводу потери хвоста файла вы продолжаете быть неправым.

Comment: @Barmaley классная идея с do-while! Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо за ответ, вы не могли бы уточнить что имели в виду когда писали о том что у меня уже есть буферизированный поток, разве FileInputStream буферизированный?

Comment: @Barmaley И к стати да а как же хвост файла удается прочитать я тоже не понимаю(((( объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: У вас `FileInputStream` обернут в `BufferedInputStream` - это первый буфер, второй буфер ваш массив `bytes`

Comment: Хвост читается, потому что при чтении хвоста `size` будет меньше `BUFFER_SIZE`, а проверка на прекращение цикла срабатывает уже **после** чтения буфера

Comment: С хвостом понял, спасибо. А вот с буферами как то не совсем, я так понимаю что если я буду использовать у экземпляра BufferedInputStream вариант метода без параметров то никакого буфера не получится, и считывание будет проходить побайтого как если бы и не было никакой обертки. А создавая массив bytes и используя его в данном варианте перегрузки метода read() я как раз буфер и получаю. Разве не так? Потому что если бы я использовал вариант read() без параметров то где же тогда окажутся сами прочитанные данные не в int amountData же они там не поместятся просто...

Comment: У `BufferedInputStream` есть свой внутренний буфер, в который он сразу читает при первом к нему обращении. Далее по мере чтения, он подкачивает в этот буфер следующие данные. Так что побайтовое чтение почти не будет уступать в скорости чтению сразу в массив. [Изучите исходники](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/BufferedInputStream.java) `BufferedInputStream` и вам все станет понятно

Answer (score 1):

Не залезая за ответом в карман, могу предложить такой вариант:

```
int amountData = in.available()/1024;
for(int n=0; n<amountData; n++){
    in.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
}

in.read(bytes, 0, in.available());
```

Comment: А что возвращает available()? И зачем этот знак процента перед 1024: %1024;?

Comment: 1) Возвращает, сколько байт можно считать из файла. 2) Это целочисленное деление. По сути я определяю, сколько раз можно считать 1024 байт, считываю их, а потом остатки.

Comment: а... хитро придумано мне такое в голову  не пришло в этом месте использовать на столько что я даже деление не признал вот что значт ломка шаблона))))

Comment: а вы не знаете метод available() сильно дорогой как его использование скажется на производительности в случае если файл окажется действительно большим?

Comment: 1) За весь процесс он вызывается 2 раза. 2) Это тот же процесс что и в окне "Свойства файла", где отображается его размер.

Comment: @Riĥard Brugekĥaim, Вообще то `%` - это оператор деления по модулю. @Павел, метод available - смотрит сколько осталось не прочитанных байт - это значит, что при делении по модулю, он каждый раз будет отводить <=1024 байта зараз.

Comment: А да, перепутал.

Answer (score 1):

Если метод работает только с текстовым файлом, я предлагаю использовать потоки ввода-вывода символов. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть так:

```
    String path = "/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/target_text.txt";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))) {

        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        System.out.println(sb);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Потоки ввода-вывода символов оборачивают потоки байтов и как раз избавят вас от подобных проблем.

Comment: Сложение строк, работает быстрее чем append.

Comment: @And, да, вы правы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно работать именно с байтами, то следующий код вам подойдет:

```
private void read() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String path = "/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/target_text.txt";
    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(path))) {

        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

        int amountData;
        while ((amountData = in.read(bytes, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) 
            sb.append(new String(bytes, 0, amountData StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Но, если ваша задача всего лишь, вывести строки на экран, то я бы порекомендовал использовать более высокоуровневый api, например с использованием stream'ов

```
String path = "/Users/pavel/Desktop/test/target_text.txt";
String content = Files
            .lines(Paths.get(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
System.out.println(content);
```

метод `Files.lines` является *ленивым*,  он не загружает весь файл целиком, а подгружает строки по мере надобности.

Comment: utf8 - многобайтная кодировка, поэтому байты одного символа могут быть прочитаны в разные проходы цикла и не будут корректно преобразованы в символы. Лучше использовать `InputStreamReader` или `CharsetDecoder`

Comment: Да, есть такое, я не подумал, что это может возникнуть